# What are the pros and cons of building an AJAX-heavy web app over one with persistent URLs?

Tags: javascript

**Original Question: Is it a bad idea to make an all JavaScript website?**

****Changed the question because this ended up being more of a discussion, but it could be helpful for others.****

In this case, I was thinking of making a website that initially delivers its overall layout using regular HTML (like a normal, basic web page), but then I plan to fill the content of the HTML content area dynamically, entirely with AJAX requests.

Users of the site won't ever be refreshing the page or going to a new page, and all other divs and elements that need to be generated will be created using AJAX (making use of lots of JavaScript functions that are on a cached external JavaScript page).

Although I'm not actually making a **forum** website, a forum's level of functionality is close to what I want to achieve.  Lots of database reading and writing too.

Is this a bad idea?  Am I not considering something that could make this potentially terrible?  Is it good performance-wise (since I'll be doing so much client-side work and less server side work)?

I realize that the page wouldn't work for people who have JavaScript turned off, but that's not a concern in this case.  I'm also not worrying about any mobile devices that don't support JavaScript, since I would probably just create a mobile-specific version of the site that doesn't use JavaScript).

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
First: Thank you for all the responses, everyone!  I really appreciate it!

Just for clarification purposes, I thought this would be a good idea mostly because it seemed like I could just say, "Hey AJAX, just give me the raw forum post data for this page and I'll do all of the HTML building on the client side."  Same DB access of course, but less server side page formatting work and less data transfer to the client.

And another important clarification: I'm not worried about search engine optimization because this forum would be a login-only network that should not be crawled or viewed by non-logged-in users.

Comment: @phooji Could you please elaborate?

Comment: This depends heavily on your target audience and therefore could not be reliably answered here.

Comment: Slightly longer answer: It sounds like you're developing a new web application application from scratch. In your situation, I would pick a design and a development strategy that gets _a lot of stuff done as quickly and as easily as possible_. That way, you can later add asynchronous JavaScript calls as needed to make stuff look slick. No need to commit to a JavaScript-only design up front -- it's much harder to get started, more brittle across browsers, and more likely to get you stuck debugging race conditions.

Comment: This is more of a discussion than a question. There would likely be some SEO problems. AJAX usually comes with a generally nice, animated interface, though. You aren't going to be making it any easier on your server, because it's still going to have to read and write just as much from the database as if it were a page load.

Comment: agreed on the debugging comment, when you could be spending that time putting together more interface. depends how much time you have, and how handy your Javascript is.

Comment: Good point about debugging.  I've never tried anything like this before, so I didn't consider the possible debugging challenges, but I'd at least be up trying it if there aren't any other major downsides that outweigh the benefits.

Comment: This discussion has real value. Instead of closing the question, why don't we change it to something like: "What are the pros and cons of building a AJAX-heavy web app over one with persistent URLs?"

Comment: Such a bad question in fact that it got a bunch of answers! Good rename, I think a bunch of people could find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

Not a crazy idea at all, but I recommend against it since it'd be hard to maintain.  You just got to know what you're getting in to.  Facebook does something similar.  The Google search interface, for example, also keeps you on the same page when you perform a search.

You might also be interested in:

Backbone.js
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

and BBQ (Back Button Query)
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html

One disadvantage is that analytics scripts won't necessarily work properly on sites built this way, depending how you build them.

Edit:

One concern is that it won't be search engine crawlable.  This can be overcome if you build the site well, probably using BBQ, and by following this spec:

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html

Comment: These are some great resources! Thanks, Jeff!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of years back, that'd be an absolute NO. But now with the newer browsers, libraries like jQuery, YUI things can be reconsidered.

Disclaimer: I'm not saying an absolute YES.

Rather, it requires careful evaluation of your requirements, user experience expectations, performance levels etc.

If your primary user base is using IE6/7 or even 8, the page speed is going to be significantly slower than FF or Chrome. There are certain cases where you've to resort to server side rendering.

The list could go on an on but you're the best judge here (unless you can be more specific with your requirements).

Recently we rolled out a JS intensive website for a major news corporation. However, to keep it performant, we also leverage server side caching and few other techniques in conjunction with client side JS.

Comment: My primary user base will ideally be people with relatively modern computers and new browsers.  Maybe I'll help to push people toward updating their browsers more often.  :P  Most of the JavaScript that I'd be adding with the all-JavaScript solution (that wouldn't be there otherwise) just has to do with HTML generation.  And as I'm sure you know...it can be frustrating to see how many people still use IE 6 and 7, haha.

Comment: You can then maybe look at webworkers!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a bad idea in and of itself, particularly if you don't care about support for browsers that don't have JavaScript enabled, but it does carry some caveats.  For instance you'll need to put a fair bit of effort into working out how your JavaScript framework should be structured, and what tools you will use.  If you don't come up with a solid solution then your website code can quickly degenerate into an unmaintainable mess.  You'll also be spending a lot more time doing cross-browser testing, as the same JavaScript code may produce different behavior in different browsers (thanks mostly to IE).

As far as performance is concerned, you really aren't doing any less server-side work.  The expensive server-side operations are your database queries, and you have to do those regardless of whether the server is returning a standalone web page or an AJAX (or JSON) snippet.  In fact, depending upon how you structure your JavaScript client you could end up doing more work.  For instance, if the JavaScript sends a separate AJAX request for each div on a page, that will be less efficient overall than allowing the server to create the content for all of the divs on the page as part of a single operation.

Comment: Ideally I was hoping to do a "give me everything I need...here's the list of stuff that I want" AJAX request, but you make a good point about much of the work being related to database queries.  I wish I had some way of determining exactly how much work I'd be saving by doing all of the HTML rendering on the client side rather than the server side.  My only other thought was that I might be saving some time by making one AJAX page request rather than several page requests (and checks to see if those pages are already cached).  But I don't know how big of a deal that is.

Answer (score 0):

Its a good idea, but lets see what could be some troubling points

what i can think of:

- The web site wont be Crawlable by any
  Search Engines.
- the SOURCE CODE of your Web site can
  be Easily stolen, and everyone will
  be able to enjoy on your hard work.
- Pages Cannot be Liked in Facebook
  (facebook needs OG Tags)
- Hard to track analytics

Comment: The source code would still be useless without the server to back it.  Someone can just as easily steal your server's generated HTML source code.  And pages absolutely could be liked in Facebook.  All Facebook needs is a URL, so as long as the JavaScript provides some way of mapping from a URL to a given UI state, it would work just fine.

Comment: You can steal my HTML, but you will need to steal HTML of all my pages, and Google will be able to detect that our sites are duplicate, while this wont be so with a FULL JS site. the Javascript will probably act like the template/logic, which we do with php/server side, and cannot be stolen. hope you get what i am trying to convey. :)

Comment: I do like the idea of keeping that hard work somewhat safe, heh.  But if it led to a reasonably big performance boost (i.e. - I could support more simultaneous users with a less powerful server), it might be worth putting the code out in the open.  In the end though, I guess it wouldn't be terrible saying "this is how I made the HTML that you can see...using these steps in JavaScript."  Good thoughts though.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is. You should always provide a non-javascript fallback site for **search engines** and people with old browsers.

Comment: Always?  Really?  What happens when you visit Facebook with JavaScript turned off?

Comment: I could always create an alternate mobile/lo-fi version of the site for older browsers.  And the other thing is, I was hoping to take advantage of all the new and fancy things that HTML5 has to offer, so I figured that I'd just detect old browsers (or when JS is off) and I'd notify users that they need to use a modern browser.  That would probably be fair, right?